# Phonegap 3.0 Facebook connect invalid app id

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova

I've installed the Facebook connect plugin with plugman and everything seems to be working. I use the following code to login with Facebook and get user details:

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function(userData) {
    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
}
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["basic_info"], fbLoginSuccess, function(error) {
    alert("" + error)
});
```

I run this piece of code inside my phonegap onDeviceReady callback, when I start the application in my iPhone simulator it goes directly to the Facebook web page but gives me an error: Invalid app ID. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: appid is invalid, as the error is saying

Comment: The app id it's showing is the same as the App ID I already use for my my website login, so it's not invalid?

Answer (score 0):

your hashkey is incorrect in facebook developer app.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YourAppName -keystore /Dekstop/YourAppNameKeyStore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

password: android